# Java : Does Runtime.getRuntime().exec() wait by default?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I have a query regarding `Runtime.getRuntime()`.
I am running the following code.

```
public class TestMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime rs = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rs.exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\sampleProgram.exe");
    rs.exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\sampleProgram2.exe");
    rs.exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\sampleProgram3.exe");
}
}
```

Now, if `sampleProgram` takes more time to execute, will the control wait for the  `sampleProgram` to complete or it will go for `sampleProgram2` and will run it parallely ? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it does not wait.

But you can wait for it to finish using the `waitFor` method.

```
rs.exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\sampleProgram3.exe").waitFor();
```

**Note:** If you use a command like `cmd start xxxxxx` the `waitFor` method won't really work, because the `start` command starts the given command/arguments in another process (This is of course a windows specific thing).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So If I create 3 different `rs` object say `rs1`,`rs2`,`rs3` and will call `waitFor()` on each object , then it will be equivalent to the code which i have provided in my question.. right ? because those 3 will be independent to each other

Comment: They will be executed one after another.